# How to select a date range based on another value

Tags: sql, date, range

I have a table with identifiers, dates and a validity bit.

```
ID | Date       |  SalesID | InValid
   |            |          |
1  | 2013-08-01 |    2     |  False
2  | 2013-08-01 |    3     |  False
3  | 2013-08-01 |    4     |  False
4  | 2013-08-01 |    5     |  False
5  | 2013-08-02 |    2     |  False
6  | 2013-08-02 |    3     |  False
7  | 2013-08-03 |    2     |  True
8  | 2013-08-03 |    3     |  False
9  | 2013-08-03 |    4     |  False
```

the ID is a unique number
there will be only one date entry per SalesID

My question is how can I pick out the ID number for any SalesID that has had an Invalid = true in the past 30 days.

so for SalesID = 2 , I want plus any other dates that fall within the 30 previous days

```
ID | Date       |  SalesID | InValid
   |            |          |
1  | 2013-08-01 |    2     |  False
5  | 2013-08-02 |    2     |  False
7  | 2013-08-03 |    2     |  True
```

I hope this makes sense. any help would be welcome

Thanks guys, really quick assistance, I still have much to learn. I am in your debt

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table a
JOIN table b ON
  b.SalesID=a.SalesID AND
  b.InValid           AND
  a.Date >= b.Date-30 AND
  a.Date <= b.Date
```

Beware... the date math may depend a bit on the SQL engine you are using, and on the actual data type of the date column.

Comment: You should add a DISTINCT in case there are multiple rows with *InValid = TRUE* within a 30 day range